# getter always returns 0

Tags: java

I'm new to java coding, so sorry for the beginner question. I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something easy but I couldn't find a solution in earlier topics.

I'm trying to build an object "computerDraw". When I create a new "computerDraw" I want the computer to decide whether he pulls 1, 2 or 3 numbers out of the int array. The numbers are pulled out random.

The numbers that are drawn should be stored in the variable "computerSumCards".

I created a getter to return computerSumCards but it returns "0" every time.

I can't figure out why that is. Thanks for the help!

```
public class computerDraw {
    int computerSumCards;
    int getAmountOfComputerCards;
    int randomCard;
    int draws = 0;

    private int[] possibleDraws = {1, 2, 3};
    int computerCanDraw = (possibleDraws[new Random().nextInt(possibleDraws.length)]);

    public void drawLoop() {
            while (draws < computerCanDraw) {
                    int[] cards = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};
                    randomCard = (cards[new Random().nextInt(cards.length)]);
                    computerSumCards += randomCard;

            }
    }

    public int getComputerSumCards() {
            return computerSumCards;
    }

    public int getAmountOfComputerCards() {
            getAmountOfComputerCards = draws;
            return getAmountOfComputerCards;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `drawLoop()`?

Comment: @Guy: no I didn't, but I received an error and found out (in another topic) that I couldn't set while loops in a class body directly. I'm still trying to figure that out. Is it related to this question? I thought there was a different problem.

Comment: I'm also wondering why this question is getting downvotes. I did research beforehand and tried to integrate/recompile and execute. If I'm doing / asking something wrong, please explain so I can avoid it when asking future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class does not "ignores" the `while` loop. The loop is inside the method `drawLoop()`. If you want it to run you need to call it explicitly

```
computerDraw draw = new computerDraw();
draw.drawLoop();
```

As a side note, class names start with capital later. `computerDraw` should be `ComputerDraw`.

Comment: calling the draw.drawLoop(); worked for me, I forgot that! Thanks! Also thanks for the naming tip - beginners mistakes :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't change `draws` value anywhere, `getAmountOfComputerCards = draws;` at this point you always assign 0.

After `computerSumCards += randomCard;` add `draws++;` and it should be fine. Without it you will get infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I fixed that just right now. However the problem is that the getter "getComputerSumCards()" returns 0 while it shouldn't . Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @BjornsBot It's working fine for me, add to the code what I mentioned and first invoke `drawLoop()` method and after that getter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also still new but try this:

```
public int drawLoop() {
        while (draws < computerCanDraw) {
                int[] cards = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};
                randomCard = (cards[new Random().nextInt(cards.length)]);
                computerSumCards += randomCard;

        }
        return computerSumCards;
}

public int getComputerSumCards() {
        return drawLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call draw.drawLoop(); but even if you call your while loop is going in infinite loop. values for draws and computerCanDraw are never getting changes and draws remains always < computerCanDraw value. You should either change  draws value or proper implement the computerCanDraw.